# Tag first observation for a user over products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table with the columns `user_id`, `purchase_date` and a `date` column in standard yyyy-mm-dd form.

Users in this table purchase multiple items of the same product (and different products) in the same month, so I needed to be able to capture the first time that they bought a particular product and then count each product by month.

I did it with the following:

```
SELECT yr, mo, COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Product = 'product_a' 
                                   THEN user_id)) AS product_a
FROM
( 
     SELECT YEAR(min(purchase_date)) AS yr, MONTH(min(pruchase_date)) AS mo,
            DAY(min(purchase_date)) AS dy, user_id, Product
     FROM daily_purchases
     GROUP BY user_id, Product
) b
GROUP BY yr, mo
ORDER BY yr, mo
```

This seems to work fine and capture what I am looking for. Does anyone have any suggestions - or is this the most appropriate way to go about it? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean a date column in standard yyyy-mm-dd form? Are you storing it as a string? That is not standard. It should be stored as a date.

Comment: You want the products in columns? One column for the min date purchased and one column for the count? If that is correct this seems like a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any source data to test ... but here is how I would approach it ... this may need some tweaking as I have not tested it with source data:

```
 Select [yr], [mo], [user_id], [firstBuy], [cntBuys] From
    (
        SELECT [yr], [mo], [user_id],
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by user_id order by purchase_date) as 'firstBuy'
            ,COUNT(*) over (partition by user_id, Product) as 'cntBuys'
        FROM daily_purchases
    ) a
    Where a.firstBuy = 1
    Group by a.yr, a.mo
```